# Why the void pointer is not allowed be returned by virtual methods?

Tags: c++

Recently I tried to compile this class

```
class Foo{
public: void virtual doSomething()=0;
void* virtual getBar()=0;//error
protected: Foo(){};
};
```

But compiler doesn't compile, and says `"ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘getBar’ with no type [-fpermissive]"`
Compiler: gnu 4.8

Comment: put `virtual` before the return type.

Comment: also avoid void pointers - you lose the power of type safety

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the syntax wrong. You need

```
virtual void* getBar()=0;
```